# Convert MySQL query from UNION to something more efficient

Tags: mysql

I have a custom messaging feature on my website and when I display the number of messages a user has, I do so using a union query since there are two types of messages.

I do so as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(m.messageid) type_a_messagecount
FROM messages m,
messagerecipients r
WHERE m.messageid = r.messageid AND
(
m.type = 0 OR
m.type = 2
) AND
r.read = 0 AND
r.trashed = 0 AND
r.deleted = 0 AND
r.userid = 1 AND
r.authorid <> 1
UNION
SELECT COUNT(m.messageid) type_b_messagecount
FROM messages m,
messagerecipients r
WHERE m.messageid = r.messageid AND
(
m.type = 1
) AND
r.read = 0 AND
r.trashed = 0 AND
r.deleted = 0 AND
r.userid = 1 AND
r.authorid <> 1
```

This works but something tells me it's horribly inefficient.

Is there a way to streamline this or am I stuck using a UNION query?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need the separate values or are they going to be added together in the end?

Comment: The two values will need to be separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select Sum(Case When M.type In(0,2) Then 1 Else 0 End) As type_a_messagecount
    , Sum(Case When M.type = 1 Then 1 Else 0 End) As type_b_messagecount
From messages As M
    Join messagerecipients As R
        On R.messageid = M.messageid
Where R.read = 0 
    And R.trashed = 0 
    And R.deleted = 0 
    And R.userid = 1 
    And R.authorid <> 1
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas...I get a "unknown column 'm.type' in 'field list'" when I try and run that.

Comment: @Tom - Might be a case-sensitive issue. I've updated the aliases to be consistent.

Comment: Thomas, that did it and it takes about the same time as the union query but looks a lot cleaner, will do some more testing and probably go with your query over the union.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
SELECT COUNT(m.messageid),m.type
FROM messages m,
  messagerecipients r
WHERE m.messageid = r.messageid AND
  m.type IN (0,1,2) AND
  r.read = 0 AND
  r.trashed = 0 AND
  r.deleted = 0 AND
  r.userid = 1 AND
  r.authorid <> 1
GROUP BY m.type
```

And then programmatically adding the results for type 0 and 2

Comment: That definitely works but it seems to run on average about .4 seconds slower than the union query.

Comment: You probably don't have the right indexes. Do you have an index on m.type? I'm pretty sure this query would be faster than the union if you had an index on `messageid` and `type` on the messages table. Can you show the explain ?

Comment: Damp, messageid is the primary unique index and there is a normal index on type.  What do you mean by the "explain"?  Is that like an execution plan?  I am using Navicat under OS X as a GUI to my MySQL server

Comment: The explain comma delimited: id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,Extra
1,SIMPLE,r,index_merge,"ixmessageid,ixuserid,ixauthorid,ixtrashed,ixdeleted,ixread","ixuserid,ixread","4,4",,24,"Using intersect(ixuserid,ixread); Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort"
1,SIMPLE,m,eq_ref,"PRIMARY,ixmessageid,ixtype",PRIMARY,4,r.messageid,1,Using where

Answer (score 1):

Subquery with a case statement will give you what you want:

```
SELECT 
    count(m.messageid), type_
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            m.messageid
            CASE 
                WHEN m.type = 0 THEN 'a'
                WHEN m.type = 1 THEN 'b'
                WHEN m.type = 2 THEN 'a'
            END as type_
            FROM 
                messages m,messagerecipients r
            WHERE 
                m.messageid = r.messageid 
                AND r.read = 0
                AND r.trashed = 0
                AND r.deleted = 0
                AND r.userid = 1 AND
                AND r.authorid <> 1
    ) as t
GROUP BY type_
```

Comment: Thanks nate, that works but like the query Damp wrote below it's on average .4 seconds slower than the union query.  Maybe the union query is the best way to do this after all?

Comment: Hmm, I would think that at least Damp's query would be faster with only one table scan. Maybe the optimizer is doing a lot a work on your union query.